# Unit of Work and Repository Pattern in MVC controller constructor injection using Unity not doing any changes to database

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unity-container, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

1.) I am a building new MVC application with 3 tier project architecture having:

1. Common Project with entities
2. Business/Service holding interfaces and logic classes and
3. Data holding repositories, interfaces, `DbContext` and `UnitOfWork`classes. I am using Unity Config to register dependencies, `DbContext` and `UnitOfWork`.

2.) I created a repository for each table and one generic repository that does basic CRUD operations.

Example Entity residing in Common Project:

```
public class MenuSecd
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public string prg_module { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int prg_numb { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public string menu_level { get; set; }
}
```

My generic Entity Logic Interface residing in Business Project:

```
public interface IEntityLogic<T> : ILogic where T : class
{
    void Create(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    void Update(T entity);
}
```

Entity Logic Class:

```
public abstract class EntityLogic<T> : IEntityLogic<T> where T : class
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    IGenericRepository<T> _repository;

    public EntityLogic(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IGenericRepository<T> repository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public virtual void Create(T entity)
    {
        if(entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
        }

        _repository.Add(entity);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }
}
```

Example Business Logic class for the entity defined in Common Project:

```
public class MenuSecdLogic : EntityLogic<MenuSecd>, IMenuSecdLogic
{
    IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    IMenuSecdRepository _repository;
    public MenuSecdLogic(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IMenuSecdRepository repository) : base(unitOfWork, repository)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public List<MenuSecd> GetItems(string usrgrp_id)
    {
        return _repository.GetItems(usrgrp_id);
    }
}
```

My Generic Repository in Data Project looks like:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected DbContext _entities;
    protected readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;
    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        _entities = context;
        _dbset = context.Set<T>();
    }
    public virtual T Add(T entity)
    {
        return _dbset.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual T Delete(T entity)
    {
        return _dbset.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Edit(T entity)
    {
        _entities.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
```

Repository Interface for the same Entity is defined as:

```
public interface IMenuSecdRepository : IGenericRepository<MenuSecd>
{
    List<MenuSecd> GetItems(string usrgrp_id);
}
```

Repository class for above mentioned interface is:

```
public class MenuSecdRepository : GenericRepository<MenuSecd>, IMenuSecdRepository
{
    public MenuSecdRepository(DbContext context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    public List<MenuSecd> GetItems(string usrgrp_id)
    {
        return _dbset.Where(m => m.usrgrp_id == usrgrp_id).ToList();
    }
}
```

My `DbContext` looks like:

```
public class DashboardContext : DbContext
{
    public DashboardContext() : base("Name=DBEntities")
    {

    }

    public DbSet<MenuSecd> menusecd { get; set; }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified);
        //future custom implementation like auditing
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My UnitOfWork looks like:

```
public sealed class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private DbContext _dbContext;
    public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
    {
        _dbContext = context;
    }

    public int Commit()
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    //disposes current object
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    //disposes all external resources
    private void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            if (_dbContext != null)
            {
                _dbContext.Dispose();
                _dbContext = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
public class DashController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMenuSecdLogic _menuSecdLogic;
    public DashController(IMenuSecdLogic menuSecdLogic)
    {
         _menuSecdLogic = menuSecdLogic;          
    }
    public void Save()
    {
         var menuSecd = new menuSecd();
         //populate all fields for entity MenuSecd
         _menuSecdLogic.Create(menuSecd);
    }
}
```

My Unity Config in App_Start looks like :

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.RegisterType<DbContext, DashboardContext>();
    container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
    container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
    container.RegisterType<IMenuSecdLogic, MenuSecdLogic>();
    container.RegisterType<IMenuSecdRepository, MenuSecdRepository>();
}
```

So when run above project everything builds fine. But when controller calls:

```
_menuSecdLogic.Create(menuSecd);
```

It reaches Entity Logic and adds a new entity to _repository at :

```
_repository.Add(entity);
_unitOfWork.Commit();
```

But when it hits next line to actually save it to database which is :

```
return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

in UnitOfWork.cs file.
It comes to dashboardContext where it finally have to save it to database. But it does execute :

```
var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified);
    return base.SaveChanges();
```

But nothing changes in database. There will be no record in database. To test I have added modifiedEntries to see if it is in context or not. By the time control reaches this point I see no modified entries at all. But in `EntityLogic.cs` it does add a new entity to local entities in repository.
I am not sure what is happening with UnitOfWork here. I ran SQL Profiler to see if it is hitting database or not. Interestingly it is not hitting database at all. But if my make following changes to EntityLogic like this:

```
public virtual void Create(T entity)
{
    if(entity == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));
    }

    _repository.Add(entity);
    _repository.Save();
    //_unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

It hits Database and records gets saved fine. But I am not getting why it is neither tracking changes nor hitting database if I use `_unitOfWork.Commit()` which I want to do. Please help.

Comment: What is the lifetime scope of your DbContext?

Comment: @SteveCzetty, I have not defined it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is the scope of your `DbContext`.  Your `UnitOfWork` and `GenericRepository<T>` classes are getting different instances.

Not super familiar with Unity, but it looks like you want to use something like this for your `DbContext` registration:

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, DashboadContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
```

This will create a single `DashboardContext` for each request, and your `UnitOfWork` and `GenericRepository<T>` classes will be working within the same context.

Comment: I get it. I understood that by default Unity registrations are "TransientLifetimeManager" and as a result my repositories my UnitOfWork and GenericRepository classes are getting different instances because using "TransientLifetimeManager" creates a new object of requested type every time.I need my application to use "PerRequestLifetimeManager". So I made all registrations using it as:

Comment: `public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, DashboardContext>();
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>));
        container.RegisterType<IMenuSecdLogic, MenuSecdLogic>();
        container.RegisterType<IMenuSecdRepository, MenuSecdRepository>();
    }`                                                               By doing this UnitOfWork and GenericRepositories share same DbContext and now I see changes to database.

Comment: `public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, DashboardContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
        container.RegisterType(typeof(IGenericRepository<>), typeof(GenericRepository<>), new PerRequestLifetimeManager());
       //cont
    }`                                                          By doing this UnitOfWork and GenericRepositories share same DbContext and now I see changes to database.

Comment: Bah.  Missed that it was an MVC project.  `PerRequestLifetimeManager` is the right one.